# Where do presentation, business logic, and data access layers and MVC components run: server side or client side?

Tags: architecture, web-applications, deployment

I have some difficulty, when trying to understand about the architecture (presentation i.e. UI layer, business logic layer, and data access layer, and MVC) and deployment (which part runs on client or server side) of web applications.

1. Nowadays, with modern frontend frameworks such as Angular, React, and Vue, does the entire presentation layer run on client side, and do the entire business logic layer and the entire data access layer run on the server side?
2. Before the popular frontend frameworks came into use, e.g. 10-15 years ago, when Java EE and Spring were the most popular, does only a small part of the presentation layer run on client side, and do most of the presentation layer, the entire business logic layer and the entire data access layer run on the server side?
3. When using MVC, is it correct that model means the same as the business logic layer, controller and view mean the same as the presentation layer?
4. With modern frontend frameworks, where are model, controller and view running: server side or client side?
5. Before the popular frontend frameworks came into use, e.g. 10-15 years ago, when Java EE and Spring were the most popular, where are model, controller and view running: server side or client side?

Thanks.

Comment: With things like redux and vuex to store state on the client, and vue-router to load view components dynamically, the situation is getting very blurred these days. You could write the whole MVC layer as the front end, and rely on api calls much like a server based MVC would rely on SQL.

Answer (score 3):

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) was not designed for the web. Its use for the web was popularized by Ruby On Rails. Depending who you ask they are using the term wrong, or they redefined it... yet, it certainly is not [what MVC meant in Smalltalk](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/2007/MVC_Originals.pdf), although a derived concept.

Why is that important? Because MVC was being used for desktop application, which did not have a big scary thing in the middle called "Internet", from which the client-side/server-side comes from.

"Internet" is a breach that is right in the middle of the View. That should answer most of your questions. I suggest the following nomenclature:

- "Frontend" exists only on the client side.
- "Presenter" exists only on the server side, it creates the "Frontend" sent to the client.
- "View" is both, sort of. I would say includes both. However, some definitions of "View" are only the "Presenter". For others the "Presenter" is separate. Also, how much of the "Frontend" code is considered "View" is not so clear cut either.

Perhaps when there is a big scary thing called "Internet" the term "View" is not so useful.

See [Model–view–presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter), let us not worry about what "Model" is there right now, will come back to that.

*Let us see your questions...*

---

> Nowadays, with modern frontend frameworks such as Angular, React, and Vue, does the entire presentation layer run on client side, and do the entire business logic layer and the entire data access layer run on the server side?

Business logic and data access happen on the server side, that is correct. Angular, et.al. handle code on the frontend.

*This does not mean that the frontend did not exist before such tools. Although it was usually much more static.*

Now, what do you mean by presentation layer?

I assume you mean a presentation tier of n-tier architecture, and not the ISO OSI layer. However, presentation tier is a concept that does not have the big scary thing in the middle called "Internet".

Well, the frontend code needs a web framework. If you look how Express.js (the web framework associated with Angular) handles MVC, you will see that a "View" in the framework is basically a template (with HTML and so on), which is populated by (what I call) the presenter on the server side. If that is part of what you call presentation layer, then no, not all the presentation layer is on the client.

---

> Before the popular frontend frameworks came into use, e.g. 10-15 years ago, when Java EE and Spring were the most popular, does only a small part of the presentation layer run on client side, and do most of the presentation layer, the entire business logic layer and the entire data access layer run on the server side?

Right, business logic and data access were also on the server.

There was less client side logic, however there was.

Using AJAX was a thing, however staying in the same page and doing dynamic load was much less common. Also stuff like [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) were not there... thus, some things we take for granted could not be done.

---

> When using MVC, is it correct that model means the same as the business logic layer, controller and view mean the same as the presentation layer?

I think you got these backwards. The model, is a *data* model, no business logic. The logic goes in the controller. Or rather that is how it used to be...

I do not follow what Web MVC folks do, but I have seen the motto "Thin Controller - Fat Model" (sometimes reversed), meaning to move logic from controllers to models.

If Model, View, and Controller are the only options you have about where to put logic, you will end up debating where to put things that are neither (a.k.a the fat).

There are other things aside from Model, View, Controller. You have views, yet you still need a router. You have a model, yet you still need data access. There are other concerns such as authentication, logs, configuration, templates, internationalization, etc... they have to go somewhere... Model, View or Controller?

Please watch [Baruco 2012: Deconstructing the framework, by Gary Bernhardt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUe6tacW3JE).

---

> With modern frontend frameworks, where are model, controller and view running: server side or client side?

Here is a hurdle: You can have a Web API first, then have a frontend framework with templates and populate them with data from the Web API.

Thus, you are passing a data model to the view. Hmm... isn't that a *viewmodel*? Wait, that is another model. So... Model–view–presenter could be that? Will come back to that.

See [Model–view–viewmodel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel).

A model is how you represent the data. It makes sense to have a model to deal with every external system. One external system is the web browser, another is the database. In fact, I would argue that the model should not *run*, it should be just data. *And now the "Thin Controller - Fat Model" folks are pissed off with me.*

*I think treating the browser as a external system is correct. However, it also useful to think you are "uploading" code to the browser, and that code... well it is a system, for which the server side is an external system and the user is another external system. Then the frontend could have a controller... just let that sink in.*

Here is another hurdle: You must have all your logic on the server. However, it makes sense to have part of the same logic on the client. It will save you some bandwidth, and will make the app more responsive. *You still need it in the server, because security.*

This means that, although your controller is in the server, you may have business logic in the client. That means that the frontend has a bit of business logic.

---

> Before the popular frontend frameworks came into use, e.g. 10-15 years ago, when Java EE and Spring were the most popular, where are model, controller and view running: server side or client side?

It was clearer back then, because most logic was on the server. With little logic on the frontend. However, guess what? Having a bit of business logic on the frontend was also a thing. I am, of course, talking about client side validations.

---

Listen, there is an idea behind all the n-tier architectures: have a functional core (application tier), have a layer for each external system (presentation tier to deal with the user, data tier to deal with the database), and then optionally insert layers in the middle, that is how you get your 5-tier architectures and so on.

*Of course, some people teach different names for the tiers.*

Speaking of inserting layers, that is what we were doing with Model–view–presenter and Model–view–viewmodel. You can imagine: View-Presenter-Viewmodel-Controller-Model. 5-tier architecture (one variant of). Here the view is the frontend, the rest is on the server side. The presenter has router, push notifications and template system. The viewmodel is the representation of the view on the server. The controller manipulates the viewmodel, the presenter sends updates to the view based on the viewmodel. The controller also talks to the model permanent storage... wait, we still need to map the model to the database... 6-tier architecture! (we can keep adding layers)

Thus, instead of trying to understand n-tiers architectures, MVC and the Ruby On Rails effects on men, I suggest to try to understand functional core and imperative shell (See [Boundaries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries)). Then you go to [clean architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4) or similar (hexagonal architecture, onion architecture, and so on) as they share the same principles.

---

*In my personal opinion, trying to use MVC for the web, at least as presented by most frameworks, is wrong. However, I am controversial like that. I strongly suggest a second opinion.*